# How can I move my WDS share?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have moved my WDS PXE share but I cannot get WDS to point to the new hard drive, it keeps sticking with its original configuration, does anyone know what else I need to configure?

**Setup**

```
Windows Server 2008 R2
Old Share: \\WIN-F3OV5FQ0R6E\DeploymentShare$   (E:\)
New Share: \\WIN-F3OV5FQ0R6E\DeploymentShare2$  (H:\)
```

**Bootsrap.ini**

```
DeployRoot=\\WIN-F3OV5FQ0R6E\DeploymentShare2$
```

When I right click my WDS server -> properties it reads that my deployment share is at E:\RemoteInstall which is of course the old share.

Comment: How did you "move" said share?  Looks like you didn't really move it.

Comment: Copied and pasted the contents to a new drive and tried to point the server to where its at, is there a wizard or something that is required to move it?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't sound like you actually moved it.

Comment: Ok so how do I move it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually move your share.

There's a process to follow, as in [this blog post](http://front-slash.blogspot.com/2012/06/windows-deployment-services-moving.html).

1. From an elevated command prompt:
   `WDSutil /uninitialize-server`
2. Move files
3. From an elevated command prompt:
   `WDSutil /initialize-server /RemInst: [local path to new location]`